# Declare generic Service Reference client object for scoping issue

Tags: c#, web-services

I have this in my web.config

If this value is live, then I want to call the live web service, and if it's not, then I want to call the test web service.

In my code I want to do something like this:

```
if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["runMode"] == "live")
{
    var client = new CallStatusAvailability.ServiceReference1
                                           .StatusAvailabilityRoomsClient();
}
else
{
    var client = new CallStatusAvailability.StatusAvailabilityRooms
                                           .StatusAvailabilityRoomsClient();
}

using (client)
{
  ...... lots of logic
}
```

The problem is that client is out of scope. I would like to be able to declare client before the if statement, but not sure what I can define it as?

I could put the using statement within the if or the else statement, but I would then have to duplicate all the logic in both.

At first I tried to create a function that could be called from the if and the else, and pass in client, but then I face the same issue of what type to declare the input client variable as, as an input to the function.

Comment: Why are you interested in wrapping the logic in a `using`? That keyword is usually used to instantiate-use-dispose of an object in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you not add both service references to your project, but a single service reference (probably to the test service) and vary the connection parameters using configuration transforms.  You would do this by setting your base `web.config` up to connect to the test service, then add a transform in `web.Release.config` to change the binding when deployed using the `Release` target.  This will simplify your logic to the point where you won't need the `if-else` construct and allow you to create the client within a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that var is declaring a variable.  If you need to use a variable in this way you can't use var as it need to be declared at a higher level of scope.  Just move your declaration to the containing block.  This assumes the service references are using the same type; if not, you need to fix that first or use dynamic if they are semantically identical.  You also can't use a using in this context and must use try catch finally.

To use the same types I would suggest generating the proxy using the channel factory or using svcutil so that your types are the same for the different service references.

```
CallStatusAvailability.ServiceReference1.StatusAvailabilityRoomsClient client = null;
try
{

   if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["runMode"] == "live")
   {
       client = new CallStatusAvailability.ServiceReference1.StatusAvailabilityRoomsClient();
   }
   else
   {
       client = new CallStatusAvailability.StatusAvailabilityRooms.StatusAvailabilityRoomsClient();
   }
}
catch(..){}
finally 
{ 
    client.Dispose();
}
```